# MongoDB date and removed objects

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, twisted, pymongo

Yesterday I had some strange experience with MongoDB. I am using twisted and [txmongo](https://github.com/fiorix/mongo-async-python-driver) - an asynchronous driver for mongodb (similar to pymongo).

I have a rest service where it receives some data and put it to mongodb. One field is timestamp in milliseconds, 13 digits.

First of all ther is no trivial way to convert millisecond timestamp into python datetime in python. I ended up with something like this:

```
def date2ts(ts):
    return int((time.mktime(ts.timetuple()) * 1000) + (ts.microsecond / 1000))


def ts2date(ts):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts / 1000) + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=(ts % 1000))
```

The problem is that when I save the data to mongodb, retreive datetime back and convert it back to timestamp using my function I don't get the same result in milliseconds.

I did not understand why is it happening. Datetime is saved in mongodb as ISODate object. I tried to query it from shell and there is indeed difference in one second or few millisoconds.

**QUESTION 1: Does anybody know why is this happening?**

But this is not over. I decided not to use datetime and to save timestamp directly as long. Before that I removed all the data from collection. I was quite surprised that when I tried to save same field not as date but as long, it was represented as ISODate in shell. And when retrieved there was still difference in few milliseconds.

I tried to drop the collection and index. When it did not help I tried to drop entire database. When it did not help I tried to drop entire database and to restart mongod. And after this I guess it started to save it as Long.

**QUESTION 2: Does anybody know why is this happening?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Python's timestamp is calculated in **seconds** since the Unix epoch of Jan 1, 1970. The timestamp in JavaScript (and in turn MongoDB), on the other hand, is in terms of **milliseconds**.

That said, if you have only have the timestamps on hand, you can multiple the Python value by 1000 to get milliseconds and store that value into MongoDB. Likewise, you can take the value from MongoDB and divide it by 1000 to make it a Python timestamp. Keep in mind that Python only seems to care for two significant digits after the decimal point instead of three (as it doesn't typically care for milliseconds) so keep that in mind if you are still having differences of < 10 milliseconds.

Normally I would suggest working with tuples instead, but the conventions for the value ranges are different for each language (JavaScript is unintuitive in that it starts days of the month at 0 instead of 1) and may cause issues down the road.

Comment: I need to store in milliseconds to make exact queries by timestamp field. I think the easiest way is to store timestamp as long.

Comment: "Python's timestamp is calculated in seconds" datetime has a microsecond field and it's actually possible to store millisecond timestamp. I guess the txmongo driver does it wrong way.

Comment: Found this comment it [pymongo driver sources](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/bson/son.py#L65): datetime.datetime instances will be rounded to the nearest millisecond when saved

Comment: Let's take a different approach: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you explain what you mean by the need to 'make exact queries by timestamp field'? With this information We can help you get to an answer that doesn't suffer from round off error.

Comment: I mean I identify some object by it's creation date (and author_id). Creation date must be in milliseconds so I can more or less confidently make queries like: `db.content.remove({"author_id": author_id, "creation_date": ts })` and also I would like to be able to make date queries on the same `creation_date` field, like `db.content.find({"creation_date": { $gt: start, $lt: end} })`

Comment: Currently I decided that it's easier to throw away date type and store simple longs. And I am okay with that. But I cannot understand the behavior described in the second question.

Comment: The ISODate object in MongoDB is extended from the JavaScript Date object. That said, if you grab the ISODate object and call its getDate() method, you will be able to convert it back into milliseconds. Any comparison such as `db.content.find({"creation_date": { $gt: start, $lt: end }})` will work properly if start/end are milliseconds; MongoDB will convert for you.

Answer (score 0):

It can be the case of different timezone's. Please use the below mentioned function to rectify it.

```
function time_format(d, offset) {
    // Set timezone
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
    return nd;
}

searchdate = time_format(searchdate, '+5.5');
```

'+5.5' here is the timezone difference from the local time to GMT time.

Comment: Hi. It's possible. But I don't think it's really the case. Because mongo and app is on the same server and difference in seconds not even  minutes. Looks like it's percision issue.